# android linux:ioctl LOOP_SET_FD failed

Tags: android, linux, ioctl

I have get the root access on my phone.In adb shell,I type the commands as below:

```
#create a file about 10M 
dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/sdcard/AAA.pdf  bs=1024  count=10000

#format this file
mkfs.ext2 -F /mnt/sdcard/AAA.pdf

#create a folder which is used to be mounted
mkdir /mnt/sdcard/aaa

#mount
mount -t ext2 -o loop /mnt/sdcard/AAA.pdf /mnt/sdcard/aaa 

chmod 777 /mnt/sdcard/aaa 

#umount
umount /mnt/sdcard/aaa
```

It runs properly. **But** if I want to mount again, it failed. After I type `mount -t ext2 -o loop /mnt/sdcard/AAA.pdf /mnt/sdcard/aaa`,it says `ioctl LOOP_SET_FD failed: Device or resource busy`. I dont know how could this happen. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

If it is already mounted, you can't mount it again unless you pass it the 'remount' option.  That option may or may not be available in Android's mount command since it is not standard mount.

Answer (score 0):

1- Android toolbox has not good support of loop devices. Try to use busybox's one.
2- Check that you have a remaining free loop device using losetup.

Answer (score 0):

For umount:

umount /mnt/sdcard/aaa

losetup -d /dev/loop0

Although on my device mounted loop fs is not accessible by none root user (dir permission 777). There is seclabel flag and I think it is a reason.